# android switch between webviews set on same layout

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was trying to switch between two different activities that contains a webview each. I get a lot of memory problems when switching them and I am trying now following: I set VISIBLE or GONE two webviews set on same layout. 
When I press a button from webviewA, loads a url on webviewB and when webviewB onPageFinished(), A is set to GONE and B to VISIBLE. Same from B to A. Problem is that url is loaded only first time...

two webviews are set on same layout like,

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/aLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/barraSocial">

                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webviewA"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:autoLink="web"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
                    android:scrollbars="none"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/bLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/barraSocial">
                <WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webviewB"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:autoLink="web"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/black" 
                    android:scrollbars="none"/>   
            </RelativeLayout>
```

onCreate activity,

```
final RelativeLayout LayoutA = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.aLayout);
final RelativeLayout LayoutB = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.bLayout);

webviewA = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewA);
webviewB = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webviewB);
```

on webviewA button click,

```
webviewB.loadUrl(UrlVista);
```

then, onPageFinished() from webviewB is fired,

```
 webviewB.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
        {   
                    @Override
                    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
                    {
                        LayoutA.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        LayoutB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: do you have the webview b button click, and webviewA.setWebViewClient implemented?

Comment: yes, already implemented! same as posted but from B to A

Comment: When you say URL is only loaded first time, do you mean the initialization URL, or the url after the first button click?  Also you have 2 Relative layouts both with fill parent.  The first one defined is going to win.  When you press the first button, and the URL comes up with the new website, it is not even on screen!

Comment: I mean "the URL after the first click". Could be,so how to force then desired webview to be positioned and on screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two RelativeLayouts.  One is essentially pushing the other off screen.  Instead of what you have, just have one relative layout with the 2 webviews:

In your xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/aLayout"                 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"                 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"                 
    android:layout_below="@+id/barraSocial">

    <WebView android:id="@+id/webviewA"                     
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"                                
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"                     
        android:autoLink="web"                     
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"                      
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:alignParentLeft="true"
        android:alignParentTop="true"//>

    <WebView android:id="@+id/webviewB"                     
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"                                
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"                     
        android:autoLink="web"                     
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"                      
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:alignParentLeft="true"
        android:alignParentTop="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then in your onPageFinished

```
webviewB.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url{                               
        webviewA.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        webviewB.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
});
```

This essentially has you setting the visibility of the WebViews themselves rather than the layouts.  The layouts in this case CAN be one on top of each other and you are using the visibility of them to turn one essentially off and on.